# using Qt to paint a parabola or any other polynomial

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

Is there a way to use Qt library to paint parabola or any other polynomial?
I tried using QPainter but there is no such option there.
Thank you

Comment: Maybe first you should find some points that will fit the equation and then you should connect them with anti-aliased painting like here http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/coordsys.html ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use QPainter then you should to use an QImage or QPixmap to display or save your output.

This is a simple code to show how it's done in a Qt Widgets Application.

This will be the MainWindow.h file.

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QImage>
#include <QPainter>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
private:
    void drawMyFunction(qreal xMin,qreal xMax);
    qreal myFunction(qreal x);
    QImage * pic;
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

and this will be your MainWindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    drawMyFunction(-3,3);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::drawMyFunction(qreal xMin, qreal xMax)
{
    qreal step = (xMax - xMin) / 1000;
    QPainterPath painterPath;
    QSize picSize(300,300);
    for(qreal x = xMin ; x <= xMax ; x = x + step)
    {
        if(x == xMin)
        {
            painterPath.moveTo(x,myFunction(x));
        }
        else
        {
            painterPath.lineTo(x,myFunction(x));
        }
    }
    // Scaling and centering in the center of image
    qreal xScaling = picSize.width() / painterPath.boundingRect().width();
    qreal yScaling = picSize.height() / painterPath.boundingRect().height();
    qreal scale;
    if(xScaling > yScaling)
        scale = yScaling;
    else
        scale = xScaling;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < painterPath.elementCount() ; i++ )
    {
        painterPath.setElementPositionAt(i,painterPath.elementAt(i).x*scale +     picSize.width()/2,-painterPath.elementAt(i).y*scale + picSize.height()/2);
    }
    // Drawing to the image
    pic = new QImage(picSize,QImage::Format_RGB32);
    pic->fill(Qt::white);
    QPainter picPainter(pic);
    QPen myPen;
    myPen.setColor(Qt::black);
    myPen.setWidth(10);
    picPainter.drawPath(painterPath);
    ui->label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(*pic)); // label is an added label to the ui
    // you can also do this instead of just showing the picture
    // pic->save("myImage.bmp");
}

qreal MainWindow::myFunction(qreal x)
{
    return x*x; // write any function you want here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [QPainterPath](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpainterpath.html)? It has [QPainterPath::quadTo](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpainterpath.html#quadTo) and [QPainterPath::cubicTo](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpainterpath.html#cubicTo) member functions that could be of help.

Comment: Thanks, but I dont see how I can use those funtions to draw even a simple parabola

Comment: @kakush A parabola can be [easily converted to a cubic Bezier path](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/335226/convert-segment-of-parabola-to-quadratic-bezier-curve).

Answer (score 0):

compute discrete points from your polynomial function and use [QPainter::drawLines](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpainter.html#drawLines-5) to draw the figure.

For instance, `y = x^2`:

```
   float xmin = 0;
   float xmax = 2;
   float step = 0.1; // experiment with values

   QVector<QPointF> points;
   float x = xmin;
   while(x < xmax)
   {
       float y = x^x; //f(x)
       lines.push_back(QPointF(x,y));
       x+= step;
   }
   painter.drawLines(points);
```

[Because the top corner in qt coordonates is (0,0)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/coordsys.html) You need to make a geometric translation for x and y after computing y.

Comment: thank you. This is exactly what I'm doing right now, but I wanted something more efficient.

Comment: @kakush. Is it slow? Because I know that large values of steps would produce a horrible parabola while low values would increase the time spent looping and drawing, for a better output.